# OpportunityFieldHistory timestamp and bulk API

Tags: bulk-api

I've turned on opportunity field history tracking for a couple of fields and can successfully query for changes using the bulk API. However, it looks like the OpportunityFieldHistory object doesn't give a timestamp for when the changes occurred which makes this useless for me. Is there any way to get the timestamp for when the changes occurred using the bulk API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CreatedDate field will indicate the date/time that particular history row was created, i.e. when the change happened.